# Haskell: Int to Char

Tags: haskell

I am using the function `fromEnum` to convert a character to its corresponding ASCII Int. For example:

```
fromEnum 'A'
```

returns 65.

Now, assuming I had a function that did:

```
(fromEnum 'A')+1
```

And then wanted to convert the returned value (66) to a Char which would be 'B'. What is the best way of doing so?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use `succ`? ([hoogle](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#t:Enum))

Comment: @MattFenwick that is because I want to set it so that if the char becomes 'Z' the successive one is 'A', but I guess I can work around that with your suggestion, thanks! :)

Comment: I'd suggest rewriting the question to describe the actual problem you're trying to solve, since your comment seems to imply that the problem you've described isn't the root one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `succ` to implement the behavior you want:

```
nextLetter :: Char -> Char
nextLetter c
    | c == 'Z' = 'A'
    | otherwise = succ c
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use `ord :: Char -> Int` and `chr :: Int -> Char` functions from `Data.Char`.

```
> chr (ord 'a' + 1)
'b'
```

But don't forget to `import Data.Char` in source file or `:m +Data.Char` in ghci.

The same thing with `fromEnum :: Enum a => a -> Int` and `toEnum :: Enum a => Int -> a`:

```
toEnum (fromEnum 'a' + 1) :: Char
```

The last part of this expression says haskell what type we are expecting to help the type system infer right type. But in this case we can drop `:: Char`:

```
isLower $ toEnum  (fromEnum 'a' + 1)
```

because `isLower` has type `Char -> Bool`. So it is expecting `toEnum  (fromEnum 'a' + 1)` to be `Char`.

Anyway, the solution of **bheklilr** is good enough :) I just wanted to show you few ways of solving your problem.

Comment: The idiomatic way for the more general problem `ord` and `chr`. I think it was a good idea to point that out. However, for this particular problem, @bheklilrs solution was clearly shorter.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Here is my code ex: intToChar 123 // "123"
intToChar :: Integer -> String
intToChar x 
    | x == 0 = ['0']
    | x == 1 = ['1']
    | x == 2 = ['2']
    | x == 3 = ['3']
    | x == 4 = ['4']
    | x == 5 = ['5']
    | x == 6 = ['6']
    | x == 7 = ['7']
    | x == 8 = ['8']
    | x == 9 = ['9']
    | x > 9 = (intToChar (x `div` 10)  ++ intToChar (mod x 10 ) )
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately your contribution is not useful here: it solves a different problem from the one asked about in the question. (Also, this isn't good code. You should avoid all the duplication. Your function can be written as `intToString x | x<10  = [toEnum (x + fromEnum '0')] | otherwise = ...`.)

Comment: Thank you for your excellent reply. I hope someone may need it, though It may not good one.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).